# Implementing SKI transformation

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus, combinators

I need to implement the following algorithm in order to convert Lambda Calculus into Combinatory Logic.

The rules are from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis

```
T[x] => x

T[(E₁ E₂)] => (T[E₁] T[E₂])

T[λx.E] => (K T[E]) (if x does not occur free in E)

T[λx.x] => I

T[λx.λy.E] => T[λx.T[λy.E]] (if x occurs free in E)

T[λx.(E₁ E₂)] => (S T[λx.E₁] T[λx.E₂]) (if x occurs free in E₁ or E₂)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
data CLExpr  =  S | K | I | CLVar Int | CLApp CLExpr CLExpr 

data LamExpr  =  LamApp LamExpr LamExpr  |  LamAbs Int LamExpr  |  LamVar Int 

skiTransform :: LamExpr -> CLExpr

skiTransform (LamVar x) = CLVar x --Rule 1

skiTransform (LamAbs y (s)) 
           | (free y s == False) = K (skiTransform(s)) --Rule 3

skiTransform (LamAbs x (LamVar y)) 
           | x == y     = I --Rule 4

skiTransform (LamAbs x (LamAbs y (s))) 
           | (free x s) = skiTransform 
                            (LamAbs x (skiTransform (LamAbs y (s)))) --Rule 5

free :: Int -> LamExpr -> Bool
free x (LamVar y) = x == y
free x (LamAbs y e) | x == y = False
free x (LamAbs y e) | x /= y = free x e
free x (LamApp e f) = (free x e) || (free x f)
```

The problem I have is, in rule 5, how to 'nest' my transformation functions as shown at the top. The inner transformation creates the type CLExpr, which then can't be used as an input for the outer transformation.

I also am not sure how to implement rule 2 and 6, which require seperating two expressions next to each other, but that isn't a priority yet.

Thanks!

Comment: to have two combinator expressions next to each other means to apply them together. you already have this case in your data type as `CLApp`. so you represent `(A B)` as `CLApp A B` and `(S A B)` as `CLApp (CLApp S A) B)`.

Answer (score 4):

To handle this nesting, you can widen the source language to a superset of both the source and target language (or said another way, generalize `LamExpr` to include constants).

```hs
-- The "union" of LamExpr and CLExpr
data LamCLExpr = S' | K' | I' | LCLVar Int | LCLApp CLExpr CLExpr | LCLAbs Int LamCLExpr
```

Then you can define injections from the two languages

```hs
fromLam :: LamExpr -> LamCLExpr
fromCL :: CLExpr -> LamCLExpr
```

And that allows you to define the transformation

```
skiTransform :: LamCLExpr -> CLExpr
```

notably using `fromCL` in the nested case.