# How does this S-K completeness rule work in Combinatory logic?

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

Wikipedia lists this rule as part of the S-K completeness basis:

> T[λx.λy.E] => T[λx.T[λy.E]] (if x occurs free in E)

`T[]` is a "term rewriter" that converts from a lambda term to the equivalent SK combinator term.

What I don't understand is, the inner `T[]` converts `λy.E` into SK combinator form, but then the outer `T[]` has to convert a term that now already includes SK combinator form in the second part of the input term.

How is this valid? As `T[]` seems to only be able to accept lambda terms.

Comment: I guess this presentation assumes that the set of SK combinator forms is a subset of lambda terms. One can work with that, or instead assume that S,K are just symbols and SK forms generate a new language. The two approaches generate the "same" theory, since the translation is natural. (I guess you received a downvote since this question is not about programming -- perhaps CS.SE is more on-topic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing SKI transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70533592/implementing-ski-transformation)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Completeness_of_the_S-K_basis) explains that: *Note that T[ ] as given is not a well-typed mathematical function, but rather a term rewriter: Although it eventually yields a combinator, the transformation may generate intermediary expressions that are neither lambda terms nor combinators, via rule (5).*